# How can I treat bit mask graceful in C++?

Tags: c++

I have met code like this.

```
    #define JOB_STATUS_PAUSED               0x00000001
    #define JOB_STATUS_ERROR                0x00000002
    #define JOB_STATUS_DELETING             0x00000004
    #define JOB_STATUS_SPOOLING             0x00000008
    #define JOB_STATUS_PRINTING             0x00000010
    #define JOB_STATUS_OFFLINE              0x00000020
    #define JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT             0x00000040
    #define JOB_STATUS_PRINTED              0x00000080
    #define JOB_STATUS_DELETED              0x00000100
    #define JOB_STATUS_BLOCKED_DEVQ         0x00000200
    #define JOB_STATUS_USER_INTERVENTION    0x00000400
    #define JOB_STATUS_RESTART              0x00000800

    DWORD func();
```

The func return a dword which is the combination of these bit-mask. I want to test the return value which status it has. I write code like this.

```
    if(ret&JOB_STATUS_PAUSED)
      string str="JOB_STATUS_PAUSED";
    if(ret&JOB_STATUS_ERROR)
      string str="JOB_STATUS_ERROR";
```

I wonder is there a graceful way to treat bit mask? I think std::bitset is not enough, I also need to get the string of the macro. I think this macro can help, but I have no idea how to use it.

```
   #define str(a) #a
   //if I input str(JOB_STATUS_PAUSED) then I can get "JOB_STATUS_PAUSED"
```

Comment: you can use bitset https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/o-1-bit-flags-and-bit-manipulation-via-stdbitset/

Comment: You should have a look at [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Putting these in an enum instead of defines might be nicer, too

Comment: Instead of hex-values, binary literals _might_ be more readable (`0b0001`, `0b0010`, `0b0100`...), but that's debatable.

Comment: Apart from code review-ish comments, I don't think there's any better way to handle this than to either name the cases explicitly in a chain of `if` statements or going in a loop and applying some function based on that (either a function that takes status as parameter and uses `switch` statement or using a map of function pointers to delegate tasks).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define str(a) L#a
        const wchar_t* statusStr[]{
            str(JOB_STATUS_PAUSED),
            str(JOB_STATUS_ERROR),
            str(JOB_STATUS_DELETING),
            str(JOB_STATUS_SPOOLING),
            str(JOB_STATUS_PRINTING),
            str(JOB_STATUS_OFFLINE),
            str(JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT),
            str(JOB_STATUS_PRINTED),
            str(JOB_STATUS_DELETED),
            str(JOB_STATUS_BLOCKED_DEVQ),
            str(JOB_STATUS_USER_INTERVENTION),
            str(JOB_STATUS_RESTART)
        };

        int len = dimof1(statusStr);
        std::vector<std::wstring> ret;

        for (int i = 0, init = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if (status & init) {
                ret.push_back(statusStr[i]);
            }
            init = init << 1;
        }
        return ret;

#undef str
```

I think this meets my requirement.